# How to applied a default wait time to visible or find or display of webElement in selenium except using Implicit wait or webdriver wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to apply a one specification to my selenium test's code as *webdriver have to wait for web element to display or load on a webpage for anytime*. It should be applicable for a every web element in the code. Is there any way to get this. Instead of applying implict wait or Webdriver wait when ever it required. I can  use this specification so that even though in future any webElement take sometimes to get visible it will wait default till it is visible.

Comment: @DebanjanB That dup is not what OP is asking. He's asking how to apply a wait to ALL `.findElement()` calls without using implicit waits or `WebDriverWait` everywhere. Your dup is how to apply a wait to ONE call. See Guy's answer for an example of what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a method which receives `By` as parameter and returns `WebElement`, and use it for all the element search instead of `driver.findElement()`

```
// Java syntax
public WebElement findElement(By by) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
    return element;
}
```

You can also put `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);` at class level instead of creating a new instance every time.